# Total combinations of $a$ apples in $b$ baskets with each basket size of $s$ $(s < a)$

Tags: combinatorics

Given $a$ apples and $b$ baskets with each basket size of $s$ $(s < a)$, in how many ways can we distribute these $a$ apples to the $b$ baskets.

I know the solution for the combinations of $a$ apples in $b$ baskets with each basket size $s \ge a$ i.e., ${a+b-1 \choose b-1}$ or ${a+b-1 \choose a}$

Note: Here apples and baskets are indistinguishable.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq) to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions. Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: are the apples undistinguishable ? are the bins distinguishable ?

Comment: Yes, here apples and baskets are indistinguishable.